# Is there any way to set the Navigator to type area default

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

My requirement is based on selection of API functions the graph type should be change .i.e like columns, line, bar... as it was demonstrated in Kendo UI examples.
                http://demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/api/index.html
     Is it possible to do the  same with stock chart. When I select only type column the actual problem is getting. The navigator scrolling to not moving till end in column type.
                Here is the js bin I worked.

http://jsbin.com/ilemel/2/edit

Is there any reason why that was not supporting in type column.

the problem is with the column type and is it possible to set the navigator to type area default and the chart type should change based on selected type.

**`Any help would be appreciated.`**

Comment: And is it possible to set the navigator series type to area .Means what ever we checked the type like column line or bar... navigator type should be area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the series type in the navigator on the fly is not supported. This is a limitation that we'd like to remove in future versions.

For the moment, you'll need to recreate the stock chart in order to change the chart type.

I've updated the code sample here: http://jsbin.com/ilemel/31/edit

Note that I keep a "master" configuration and make a copy of it for each instance:

```
var config = { ... };

function createChart() {
    $("#chart").kendoStockChart(
        // Create a deep copy
        $.extend(true, {}, config)
    );
}
```

This is the recommended approach for reusing configuration objects, as the chart expands some properties in place.

Comment: Perhaps it will be easier to understand if we pass the parameters directly: http://jsbin.com/ilemel/39/edit